# Scraping filename from string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a links that I am trying to scape filenames from.

The links go like this.

```
http://server1.cdn.net/d/7ukx6bfktz3hrqqjftyj3bsgbrczgn4awsbmuve2tahzbvqkfahd4m3c/cgqf5cky14bq.mp3
```

What I would like from this link is the **cgqf5cky14bq** part, the regex should also be able to wildcard the subdomains like server1, server2 etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Uhm... I've an idea: you can study regex :D This is really a trivial thing to do. `$` will be your man.

Comment: Just for the sake of it: `/([^/]+)\.\w+$`, the result will be in the first capture group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pathinfo()`:

```
print_r(pathinfo('http://server1.cdn.net/d/7ukx6bfktz3hrqqjftyj3bsgbrczgn4awsbmuve2tahzbvqkfahd4m3c/cgqf5cky14bq.mp3'));

Array
(
    [dirname] => http://server1.cdn.net/d/7ukx6bfktz3hrqqjftyj3bsgbrczgn4awsbmuve2tahzbvqkfahd4m3c
    [basename] => cgqf5cky14bq.mp3
    [extension] => mp3
    [filename] => cgqf5cky14bq
)
```

http://codepad.org/QEN9Anhq